# SendGrid Sending Multiple Copies

Tags: python, heroku, sendgrid

I'm using SendGrid to send emails from my python-based Heroku app.I'm okay with it taking 10 or so minutes to get to my inbox, but I'm receiving three copies of the message and I can't figure out why. Here is the relevant code:

```
import sendgrid
from sendgrid import SendGridError, SendGridClientError, SendGridServerError
sg = sendgrid.SendGridClient('xxx@heroku.com', 'xxx')
message = sendgrid.Mail()
message.add_to('John Doe <xxx@xxx.com>')
message.set_subject('Example')
message.set_html('Body')
message.set_text('Body')
message.set_from('Dark Knight <xxx@xxx.com>')
message.add_attachment('image.jpg', './image.jpg')
status, msg = sg.send(message)
@app.route('/test2')
def test2():
    sg.send(message)
    return "sent"
```

When I go to the relevant route I get 'sent' returned and the email is sent, but again, it send three copies. I'm not sure why. Any help would be great.

Comment: I get the same issue when I run it from bash.

Comment: You have `sg.send(message)` two times, what are you running in bash?

Comment: the script, I wasn't sure if it was being called multiple times because of how the heroku page loads.

Answer (score 0):

Emails one and two:
`status, msg = sg.send(message)` would send two emails and then set `status` and `msg` to the response object.

Email three: after you load the route `sg.send(message)` sends the next email.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use sendgrid sendmail api to send email. its efficient, fast way to send emails.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `sg.send(message)` three times in your code.

It is called twice here: `status, msg = sg.send(message)` - this will send one mail for `status` and log it's response to that variable. It will then send again for `msg` and log it's response to that variable as well.

Then when the user hits the `/test2` the function is called again, making it three messages in total.

Here's how you might change it to log responses but just send the one message out:

```
import sendgrid
from sendgrid import SendGridError, SendGridClientError, SendGridServerError
sg = sendgrid.SendGridClient('xxx@heroku.com', 'xxx')

def sendMessage(options):
    message = sendgrid.Mail()
    message.add_to('John Doe <xxx@xxx.com>')
    message.set_subject('Example')
    message.set_html('Body')
    message.set_text('Body')
    message.set_from('Dark Knight <xxx@xxx.com>')
    message.add_attachment('image.jpg', './image.jpg')

    // send the message and log the results to status
    msg = sg.send(message)
    return msg

@app.route('/test2')

def test2():
    // send the message, pass any options like email address (not required)
    status = sendMessage(options)
    return status
```

I've added a new function above to send out the message and given it an optional `options` var, so you could use that to pass things to the message, like a different email address, or subject.